# What's an example of a function in $L^1(0,1)$ but not $L^p(0,1)$ for $p>1$?

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces

> What's an example of a function in $L^1(0,1)$ but not $L^p(0,1)$ for $p>1$?

I've seen [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55170/is-it-possible-for-a-function-to-be-in-lp-for-only-one-p) but this is on an infinite domain. I'm interested only in $(0,1)$. I tried playing around with $\int_0^1 \frac{1}{x^a\log^b(x)}dx$ but haven't found success. I was trying to think of some transformation of the given answer to the domain $(0,1)$ but it can get messy.

If possible, I would prefer a hint to an outright answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are definitely on the right track: I would consider something like 
$$
f = 
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{x^a(\log x)^b} & \text{if}\ x \in (0,0.5) \\
1 &\ \text{if}\ x \in [0.5,1)
\end{cases}
$$
so that you don't need to worry about integrability at $1$. Now you only need to play around with $a$ and $b$.

A choice that works is the following:

> $a = 1$, $b = 2$. For a proof you can check the computations for [part (c) in the answer I gave to this other question.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1766083/real-analysis-qualifying-exam-practice-questions/1766147#1766147)

Comment: Thanks! I tried the numbers you suggested but wasn't thinking about the issue at $1$ under the transformation $u=\log(x)$.

Comment: @ZacharySelk: I'm glad this was helpful! :)